# How Amazon SNS works with NodeJS and Xamarin?

Tags: c#, node.js, amazon-web-services, xamarin.forms, amazon-sns

I have `Xamarin.Forms` as my client side and `Node` as my Server side. Currently I am implementing a push notification feature. I found Amazon providing it through `Amazon SNS`. I have gone through the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-mobile-application-as-subscriber.html). It states that we have to publish all our message to a topic and those who subscribe it, can get the push notification but my requirement is different. I have a role based app. If I send a request to another person, it should trigger a push notification. Basically I need to target specific device that use my app and not the topic publish subscribe things.

Is this possible with Amazon SNS or should I choose some other service which fulfill my requirement as I stated above? Please Help me out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can notify individual devices either through console or by API. Here are some information. [Via console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-send-directmobile.html). You can also specify a `TargetArn` with the API call, which can be an endpoint URL.

Comment: I've no experience with C#. You just need to figure out the Arn of the device that you wish to send the notification. And with the publish call, just need to `TargetArn` instead of `TopicArn`.